# Splitting a string based on a number/char pattern - Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split a string with the following patterns:

```
abc3xab     -> ('abc', '3xa', 'b')
abc3x3xab   -> ('abc', '3x3x', 'ab')
abc3xxab    -> ('abc', '3xx', 'ab')
abc34xxab   -> ('abc', '34xx', 'ab')
abc100ab    -> ('abc100ab')
abc10axb    -> ('abc10axb')
```

That's it, the pattern is '[0-9]+x[a-z]' (if there's a number followed by an `'x'` and any char between `a-z`. 
I tried

`String[] words = string.split("[0-9]+x")`

but then I only got `abc` and `ab`. What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please see numerous Q&A: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+split+keep+separator

Comment: Use this regex and use groups instead of split : `(.*?)((?:[0-9]+x+)+)(.*)`

Comment: I will reopen the question as the solution is not an evident one.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a combination of positive lookahead and lookbehind to keep the delimiter:

```
String[] words = string.split("((?<=[0-9]+x)|(?=[0-9]+x))");
```

[Sample IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/zswXVb):

```
String[] words = "abc3xab".split("((?<=[0-9]+x)|(?=[0-9]+x))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
String[] words1 = "abc3xxab".split("((?<=[0-9]+x)|(?=[0-9]+x))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words1));
String[] words2 = "abc34xxab".split("((?<=[0-9]+x)|(?=[0-9]+x))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words2));
String[] words3 = "abc100ab".split("((?<=[0-9]+x)|(?=[0-9]+x))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words3));
String[] words4 = "abc10axb".split("((?<=[0-9]+x)|(?=[0-9]+x))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words4));
```

Results:

```
[abc, 3x, ab]
[abc, 3x, xab]
[abc, 3, 4x, xab]
[abc100ab]
[abc10axb]
```

Comment: Java does not support infinite width lookbehind. This does not work. Upvoters give you much credit though :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm aware of this limitation but it's a bit weird as it worked fine on my machine (in Java 8).

Comment: It works for some reason, but the output is also weird. I will re-edit.